# Calendar Overlay - Cannot complete this action. Please try again

Tags: error, calendar, service-pack

I have a rather strange issue this morning.

Running SP2010.

One I attempt to add a Calendar overlay to an existing Calendar, I get an error:

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

The URL which i'm entering is definitely correct. I've tried with the Friendly DNS Name and with the Server Name : http://mysharepoint/site ; http://server1/site. Both giving the same error.

Here's the catch though. Calendars on my Rootweb/Top Level Site works fine.

This all started after installing Service Pack 1 for Sharepoint 2010.

ULS Is throwing the following exceptions:

> VtemplateManager::loadUncustomizedFormSchema failed with error code
>   0x80004005.

and

> Site Enumeration Stack:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.MashUpCalendarListAccessor.OpenWeb(String
>   webUrl, SPWebApplication webapp)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AggregationCustomizePage.RetrieveListsWithCalendarView(String
>   webUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AggregationCustomizePage.UpdateListDropDownList()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AggregationCustomizePage.BtnResolve_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   ASP._layouts_aggregationcustomize_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)      at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. For some reason , the Team Discussion List was broken on all the WEBS where I coudln't add the calendar overlays. Also, the Site content and Structure page was not opening. Thanks to this fix here: http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/607651/#msg_607651 I managed to fix the problem by deleting the "Team Discussion" List. I have no need for it, so I didn't restore it.